# Log messages in Splunk are shown as ASCII numbers

Tags: log4j2, splunk

Our Spring Boot applications run inside Docker containers. We log using e.g. log4j2.

When I use in my Spring Boot application the Spring log4j2.xml configuration file (see below) then log statements are readable (as plain text) in the Docker logs. When I try to read them in Splunk the message is shown like:

```
message=['123', '34' '116', ... ]
```

When I remove the log4j2.xml file, then all logs are readable again both in the Docker logs as in Splunk.

Why is this happening?
How can I make the messages readable in Splunk?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>
                    [%-5level] %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1} - %msg%n
                </pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="nl.mycompany.xyz" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" />
        </Logger>
        <Root>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console-Appender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the encoding as UTF-8 in your log4j configuration? You can find examples here - 
<param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10301_01/doc.1013/e10292/logging.htm

Comment: @Lokesh - please promote your suggestion as the answer and I will reward the bounty for you. Thank you very much. I tried many things, this simple solution works!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I have added the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the param `Encoding` to your log4j configuration (log4j2.xml file) as `UTF-8`.

```
<param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
```

I have added the above property to your configuration -

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console-Appender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>
                [%-5level] %d{MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] [%c{1} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>
</Appenders>
```

You can find full examples here for different configurations - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10301_01/doc.1013/e10292/logging.htm